# Dynamically activate "OnClick" function in command button in a subform in access 2007

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2007

I've created a form with 3 subforms in it to display an user's details and the inventory the user has. The form enables user to update the details displayed. Thus each subform has a "save" and "undo" button. I'm trying to create a "Clear All" button on the parent form which undo all changes there are in all the 3 subforms.

I don't really want to retype the same codes used in the 3 "undo" buttons, so is there a way to make use of the Onclick function of the 3 buttons?

I've tried the following with one subform first:

```
Private Sub ClearAllParentForm_Click()
    Me.Subform1.Form.clearButton_Click
End Sub
```

However, the form invokes the subform's beforeupdate event instead (a messagebox that prompts user to save the updated record). I've also tried to change the codes to Me.Subform1.Form.Undo which produces the same issue. Is there somewhere which I did wrongly or is my concept wrong?

Sorry, just started using Microsoft Access 2007 only recently so quite confused with some stuff.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@JeffO is right, but I thought I'd expand on what he said with a little more guidance.

If you have the following in a Worksheet module:

```
Private Sub ClearButton_Click()
    'ClearButton code here.
End Sub
```

You need to move the ClearButton code into a Sub in a general module. So in a new module, you need the following:

```
Sub clearbtn()
    'ClearButton code here.
End Sub
```

Now, back in the Worksheet module you call this code on button click with one line:

```
Private Sub ClearButton_Click()
    Call clearbtn
End Sub
```

Making these changes to your event triggers will allow you to use them elsewhere in your code.  The implicit lesson here is that you can't call an event trigger sub from elsewhere in VBA, but other subs can be called from within an event trigger.

Comment: Oh great! It works! Thanks so much to both of you. One question if you both dont mind. Is there a difference in using a general module instead of putting a public sub in each of the subform then call the sub from the main form? Since I'm only using the Clear Button codes only in this parent form.

Answer (score 1):

You need three sub routines that are separate from the button's click event. Have each button call their respective sub routine or function. Then the one single button can call all three.